# Understanding Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to Android development and Firebase. I am making an app in Java.

I've used Firebase Auth for sign-in and sign-up of a user. There are other variables I want to associate with each user (e.g. max squat, it's a fitness app) however, I saw a YT video that said you cannot do this with Firebase Auth. I will need to create a second array/ database to store this user information...if I were to use Firebase DB am I able to easily reference the variables/info stored for my methods?..e.g. If a user's max squat is stored can I easily reference it/assign it to a local variable so I could calculate how many reps they should do? Finally, if the user signs in using Firebase Auth, how do I link this with their info/variables stored in Firebase DB?

Apologies if my use of proper terminologies is lacking, as I said I'm relatively new.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use it with Firebase Auth. You'll have to use Firebase realtime DB for that. There is a lot of content on using Firebase for android applications. Can you elaborate a little more on what exactly are you trying? Do you want to access the data while authenticating the user?

Comment: Not while authenticating. During the main functions of my app I will need to reference variables who's values will be stored on Firebase DB, e.g. to calculate the number of squats to do, I will need to access the users 1 rep max for squat, which will be stored in the database. Part of my question was how easy is it to access these variables stored on Firebase DB for use in methods. I think SlothCoding has cleared most things up for me :)

Comment: You call Google Ok?? Just gev them a Call!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Auth is used only for users to SignIn and SignUp. You should continue using Firebase Auth for that part of your application. There is something called `Uid` and this is created during registration of a user with Firebase Auth. You can get this with (if user is logged in):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
```

Then you can use this `uid` as an ID for your database item. When creating a new user in Firebase Realtime Database. Let's say you have a Model class named `User.class`.

```
public class User {
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public int squats;
    ...
    ...
    
    public User() { //Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    public User(String username, String email) { 
       this.username = username;
       this.email = email;
    }
```

And so on, you need getters and setters I guess you know that part. Then you can do this:

```
User user = new User(username, email);
user.setSquats(10);
...
...
//Add all data you need to add
```

Then you can set this value to Database under `"users"` reference which you need to create earlier like this:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user);
```

This will create a new child under "users" inside Realtime database with all the values you have inside `User.class`. If you want to get those values back, just use this:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference databaseUsers = database.child("users");
User myUser = null;
Query usersQuery = databaseUsers.orderByChild("username").equalTo(uid); //you can use any value to order as you want, or you don't have to, there is many options for this query
usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         try {
             for (DataSnapshot user : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                 myUser = user.getValue(User.class);
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: You are welcome if there is anything else you need just tell me and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: My app records weights and reps for each exercise the user does. I will need to be able to query these records in order to calculate weight and reps for the next workout. Example query: where uID = x and workoutID = y and exerciseID = z get weight and reps... Am I better to use Firestore as I have read it's easier to query, or is Firebase Realtime DB capable of the fairly simple queries like the one above?

Comment: The real-time database is really for, as it is called, real-time data. If you don't need some real-time changes in your app then you can use Firestore to save your data. So if you are saving data from today's workout for tomorrow you can use Firestore. It's just what you like to use. Best for you is to check this link and take the quiz below: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore?authuser=0

Comment: And if this answer helped you to solve your question, mark it as a solution for other users to see. If anything better comes up in the future just change. Happy coding!